# How to clone <script> tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone

I have the following code (simplified to see the logic behind):

```
<div id="alfa">Text
    <script>
        $("#alfa").click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    </script>
</div>
<script>
    var clone = $("#alfa").clone().attr("id",$("#alfa").attr("id")+"_1");
    $("#alfa").after(clone);
</script>
```

I need to see "alfa_1" when I click in the cloned Text, but nothing happens.

When I use clone(true,true) that works, but I don't see the  code of the cloned div in Firebug to see what really happens.

Also I don't know why clicking the original div the alert is triggered twice.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What are you trying to achieve with this? Would it not be far easier to define a function, and call that twice?

Comment: You could add a class (.alfas) to all of the items then use $('.alfas').live() instead of .click. Then you don't have to worry about cloning the events.

Comment: In every browser, you can and should use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`. Always.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of any scenerios where you'd want to duplicate a script, instead of just reusing it. You can just use the "withDataAndEvents" parameter of `clone()` to copy events.

Comment: I have a very huge and dinamic form with some groups of fields that must be cloned. Some of the fields in each group have scripts that modify the behavior of other fields. Yes, it would be an option but I want to see the alternatives, since I cloned the fields I hoped the scripts will cloned too.

Comment: You really, really don't want to conceptually bind scripts and elements. Elements have event handlers. Your script creates an event handler. You should copy the *event handlers* and not the entire script. Just stop trying to clone the script and use `clone(true)` and it will work (as long as you don't have hard references to the calling object in your event handlers, which you don't here, and you shouldn't.)

Comment: @MattBall could you explain your suggestion?

Comment: Note that in jQuery, cloning a script element will cause it to be executed, even if it has already been executed, which is different to how *cloneNode* works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to see "alfa_1" when I click in the cloned Text, but nothing happens.

Doing DOM or innerHTML manipulations on `<script>` elements is inconsistent in browsers and doesn't really make any sense in terms of the JavaScript execution cycle. Avoid it in all cases.

If you want to copy DOM elements together with their jQuery event handlers, use `clone(true)`:

```
<div id="alfa">Text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#alfa').click(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
    var clone= $('#alfa').clone(true);
    clone[0].id+= '_1'; // sorry, I couldn't bring myself to do this the jQuery way
    $('#alfa').after(clone);
</script>
```

Comment: So +1 for *"I couldn't bring myself to do this the jQuery way"*

Answer (score 1):

The alert for the original div is triggered twice because the script is defined inside the div.  Move the script out of the div and it should work as expected:

```html
<div id="alfa">Text</div>
<script>
    $("#alfa").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
</script>
```