# How to clone element with jQuery containing id, name and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, velocity

I have a table that I want to duplicate. This table contains input with id and name. This table contains javascript also.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="text_1" name="text_1"/>
        <script>
            jQuery( "#text_1" ).on( "change", function() {
                alert("do...");
            });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can easily change id and name from text_1 to text_2 like this :

```
jQuery(clone).find("*").each(function(index, element) {

if(element.id)
{
    var matches = element.id.match(/(.+)_\d+/);

    if( matches && matches.length >= 2 ) {

        element.id = matches[1] + "_" + demandeNumber;
    }
}

if(element.name)
{
    var matches = element.name.match(/(.+)_\d+/);

    if( matches && matches.length >= 2 ) {

        element.name = matches[1] + "_" + demandeNumber;
        element.value = "";
    }
} 
});
```

But how can I change id of javascript from this :

```
jQuery( "#text_1" ).on( "change", function() {
            alert("do...");
        });
```

to

```
jQuery( "#text_2" ).on( "change", function() {
            alert("do...");
        });
```

I have try to change this but if the cloned input change, events are not throw.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use event delegation instead? `$(document).on('change', 'input.someClass', function(e) { });`? The way you have it seems pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

See the Jquery method .clone():

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

For use:

```
//That true param indicates that event handlers should also be cloned
var cloneElement = $("yourElement").clone(true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/5/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but I know this method.

I'm just having trouble to clone javascript...

Comment: So then write your javascript so that it is not specific to that element, and pass it 'this'.
    `jQuery(this).on( "change", function() {
                alert("do...");
            });`
Then use the .clone() method.

Comment: Info about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534476/how-to-clone-script-tags-with-jquery#7534557 The script is cloned but don't execute: http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/7/  Example how [events can be delegated](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-event-delegation-in-4-minutes/) to target elements: http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/8/

Answer (score 0):

Okay but I have created macro (velocity macro) for my input, select and other field and script are integreted on macro to avoid to call javascript outside macro like this

```
#macro( textField $hasTr $hasTd $hasLabel $hasError $label $attr $size $maxLength $helpText $isReadonly $isMandatory $autofocus $beanValue $bean )
#if( $hasTr ) <tr> #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) <td class="label"> #end
        #if( $hasLabel ) 
            #if( !$isReadonly ) <label for="$attr"> #end #text("$label") #if( !$isReadonly ) </label> #end  #if( $isMandatory ) <span class="mandatory">*</span> #end
        #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) </td> #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) <td class="value"> #end
        #if( $isReadonly )
            <input type="hidden" id="$attr" name="$attr" value="$!escUtils.escapeHtml( $!beanValue )" />
            <span class="readonly">$!beanValue</span>
        #else
            <input type="text" maxlength="$maxLength" id="$attr" name="$attr" value="$!escUtils.escapeHtml( $!beanValue )" size="$size" #if( $autofocus ) autofocus="autofocus" #end />
        #end

        #if( $helpText != "" )
            <img src="#media("picto/16x16/help.png")" id="${attr}_image" alt="" />
            <script>
                #set( $imageId = "${attr}_image" )
                jQuery( "#$imageId" ).qtip( {
                    prerender: true,
                    content : { text : "$!helpText" },
                    show: { delay: 1 },
                    effect: false,
                    position: { my: 'top left', target: 'mouse', viewport: jQuery(window), adjust: { x: 10, y: -15 } },
                    style: { classes: 'qtip-lgcf qtip-rounded' }
                });
            </script>
        #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) </td> #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) <td class="error"> #end
        #if( $hasError ) #if( $bean.errors.containsKey( "$attr" ) ) #set( $errorValue = $!bean.errors.get("$attr") ) <span>#text("$errorValue")</span> #end #end
    #if( $hasTr || $hasTd ) </td> #end
#if( $hasTr ) </tr> #end
```

## end

I should be able to update id in script for each field and reload javascript ...

Comment: Hello Franck, I don't know what is the [velocity](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/velocity/info), but you could try to add this information to your question also together with the velocity tag. (Or maybe ask a new question? I dunno.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.
    1.  Use regular expression and replace old ids with new one.
    2.  Take javascript block out and create function like:

```
    <script>
    onTextChange = function(obj)
    {
    alert("do....");
    }
    </script>
```

and use  change event of textbox to call this function

```
    <input type="text" id="text_1" name="text_1" onChange="onTextChange(this);"/>
```